# Modify Scroll Duration Based on Curve/Equation/Formula

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I need to scroll to the top, and am looking to modify the duration of the scroll based on how far down the document the viewport was before being scrolled. I want to add smaller increments of time as the scroll length increases. So what I'm having trouble working out is how to apply a curve to a number, an equation I assume. My maths is rusty.

As an example, how can I do something like:

```
0 to 1000 pixels -> 300 (+300)
1001 to 2000 -> 500 (+200)
2001 to 3000 -> 700 (+200)
3001 to 4000 -> 800 (+100)
4001 to 5000 -> 900 (+100)
```

And then keep adding increments of 100 for every 1000 pixels after that. Or a curve then comes to a minimum of adding 100 for every 1000 once it gets to a point.

I know I can do the above with `if/else if` statements, but I'm looking to do it with maths, for brevity and so it's easier to play with the values.

Sorry as I'm sure this information already exists elsewhere, but I'm not sure how to phrase a search to find the answer I'm looking for. Just a pointer to the correct type of maths or a tutorial would be enough, but of course a more detailed answer would also be appreciated.

I would also be interested in any advice on what is going to feel more natural for this particular use-case. I tried:

```
var duration = Math.ceil ( $('html').scrollTop() / 1000 ) * 300;
```

But it feels too slow for longer distances.

**Update**

Regarding the `if/else if` option, I came up with the below pseudo-code, which uses `if/else if` but has some flexibility, being compact. I would still like to replace the `if/else if` statements with some maths.

```
num = scrollTop
duration = 0
while ( num > 0 ) {
    a = Math.ceil(num/1000)
    if ( a >= 4 ) {
        duration += 100
    } else if ( a >= 2 ) {
        duration += 200
    } else {
        duration += 300
    }
    num -= 1000
}
```

**Update 2**

I have implemented this in lieu of a better solution, here is the JS:

```
var num = $('html').scrollTop();
var duration = 0;
while ( num > 0 ) {
    var a = Math.ceil(num/1000);
    if ( a >= 4 ) {
        duration += 100;
    } else if ( a >= 2 ) {
        duration += 200;
    } else {
        duration += 300;
    }
    num -= 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Epilepsy Warning!

You can use 'recursive' calls to `requestAnimationFrame` with a value changing inside it to control the scroll speed.

### examples:

**Constant speed and constant acceleration:**

```js
var speed = 3;
var position = 2000;
var acceleration = 1.3;
window.scrollTo(0, position);
scrollToTopAnimated();


function scrollToTopAnimated() {
  requestAnimationFrame((delta) => {
    var deltaSec = delta / 1000;
    speed += acceleration * deltaSec;
    position -= speed * deltaSec;
    window.scrollTo(0, position);
    if (position > 0)
      scrollToTopAnimated();
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, yellow, green, blue, red, yellow, green, blue);
}
```

```html
<h1> Hello World </h1>
```

**Or with a sin wave as acceleration:**

```js
var speed = 2;
var position = 2000;
var posOnSin = 0;
var sinSpeed = Math.PI;
window.scrollTo(0, position);
scrollToTopAnimated();


function scrollToTopAnimated() {
  requestAnimationFrame((delta) => {
    var deltaSec = delta / 1000;
    position -= speed * deltaSec + Math.sin(posOnSin) * deltaSec * 2;
    posOnSin += sinSpeed * deltaSec;
    window.scrollTo(0, position);
    if (position > 0)
      scrollToTopAnimated();
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, yellow, green, blue, red, yellow, green, blue);
}
```

```html
<h1> Hello World </h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting idea. But I'm looking to control the scroll with a linear speed or with the various options offered by jQuery/Velocity (easeInOut etc.) rather than acceleration like this, although it does achieve the same overall objective to a point.

Comment: Added sin wave. I just can't find an easy way to have a general formula for this.

Comment: Thanks. Also for reminding me of "formula", I knew there was another word I was missing!